# Galaxy Note II MTP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, android, samsung, usb-drive, mtp

I bought a branding new Galaxy Note II and I tried to mount its storage to my ubuntu laptop.

As you know, Android 4.0+ uses MTP by default. Android 4.1 doesn't support USB Mass Storage anymore! So I have to use MTP to open my files via USB.

I followed [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access) to get it work.

It worked only for External Memory Card. but the internal cannot be reached!

```bash
$mount

/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda5 on /media/Islamics type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda8 on /media/Technology type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7 on /media/Misc type fuseblk (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/anass/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=anass)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
mtpfs on /media/GalaxyNote2 type fuse.mtpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,user=anass)
```

Comment: I tried to use the same article but for me even mtp-detect hangs. Did your phone connect right away or did you have to make any changes to Ubuntu?

Comment: I got mtp-detect to work by installing the 1.1.5 libmtp from raring, but now it hangs trying to access the device.

Comment: MTP is one of the things that really annoyed me when someone decided that it's better and easier to use than plain old usb storage access profile.

Comment: I quit using USB storage way back at 2.3 - I found adb push/pull to be much faster for larger files. But I know some people abhor the command line...

Answer (score 5):

MTP is one of the things that really annoyed me when someone decided that it's better and easier to use than plain old usb storage access profile. I had some success transferring files over MTP but lots of frustrating hangs as well. I just can't have something that works only on 13th day of a month, providing it's not raining and that your phone faces east....

It is simply useless in terms of reliability, at least on Linux.

For this reason I've switched to the app called FolderSync and set it up with my own SSH server. It is absolutely a bliss, because I've never had to worry about the sync again.

Every file I want is uploaded to my server, new files that I drop on the server appear on the device without my intervention. The guy who develops it is really responsive in fixing bugs.

I'm in no way affiliated to this guy but I thought it's worth sharing something that just works.

PS. It supports many other online services for data storage too.