# How to connect LG P 880 4x hd with PC?

Tags: 12.04, usb, smartphone, mtp, lg

I would like to connect my LG P 880 4x hd with my PC. I have Ubuntu 12.04. The  MTP mode doesn't work and I don't know what to do? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215528/galaxy-note-ii-mtp-on-ubuntu-12-04 (attempt to use MTP, on 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this howto on getting Go-MTP installed:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html